# Solve for $x$ in $c_1x=c_2\tan(c_3x)-c_4\tan(c_5\tan(c_3x))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I've spent quite a lot of time trying to solve this equation, but I can't even begin to wrap my head around it.

I need to solve for $x$:

$\alpha x=\beta \tan(\gamma x)-\delta\tan(\zeta\tan(\gamma x))$

Does anyone have an idea on how to go about it?

Comment: Only numerical method is to be adopted. Analytic solution not possible.

Comment: Could you recommend a numerical method I could use here?

Comment: Newton-Raphson iteration is often used. There would be multiple periodic solutions depending on seed value.

Comment: This will hopefully get me started. Many thanks!

Comment: $x_{n+1}=x_n-f/f' $; so you have to find the derivative and plug it into the denominator.

Comment: This may be implemented when all the coefficients are numerical values.

Comment: Provide at least the conditions for the five constants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of good points have been already given in answer.

Sumppose that you are looking for the *first positive* zero of function

$$f(x)=\alpha x-\beta \tan(\gamma x)+\delta\tan(\zeta\tan(\gamma x))$$ If we assume $\zeta>1$, the first solution will be such that
$$\frac 1 \gamma \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi }{2 \zeta }\right) <x <\frac 1 \gamma \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{3\pi }{2 \zeta }\right)$$ and a bisection method could be the easiest. Otherwise (but it could be risky, is to start at the midpoint of the interval and use Newton method with
$$x_0=\frac 1 {2\gamma}\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{8 \pi  \zeta }{4 \zeta ^2-3 \pi ^2}\right)$$

Trying for $ \alpha=1$, $\beta=2$, $\gamma=3$, $\delta=4$, $\zeta=5$, we should have
$$\frac{1}{3} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi }{10}\right)<x<\frac{1}{3} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{3\pi }{10}\right)\implies x_0=\frac{1}{6} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{40 \pi }{100-3 \pi ^2}\right)$$ and Newton iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.17669830 \\
 1 & 0.17519807 \\
 2 & 0.17520346
\end{array}
\right)$$